# Using Devise + OmniAuth for Twitter OAuth 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm using `devise (4.8.1)` and `omniauth-twitter` and I have "Login with Twitter" working. A user can sign in (a `User` is created if it doesn't exist yet), the session is persisted and I can store their access token in the database to do further API requests.

For some new Twitter API endpoints I have to upgrade to OAuth 2:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0

I'm wondering what's the current way of accomplishing that, I can see there's a `[omniauth-oauth2][1]` gem but I don't see how this hooks into Twitter and Devise.

I could just implement the callback endpoints from the Twitter's OAuth 2 but I'm unsure how I'd feed that information to Devise then so it takes care of the session persistence.

Any idea where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this new gem help? https://dev.to/unasuke/omniauth-twitter2-gem-how-to-authenticate-twitter-account-by-oauth-20-on-your-rails-app-5fm7